# Sql 2008 Developer to Sql Azure Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, migration, azure, azure-sql-database

Hi My company is deciding for switching its existing application to azure platform (only Sql Part). So we need to upload our db from local to cloud. For migration i came across various tools like 
1. cerebrata 's tools 
2. SqlAzure Migration wizard
3. Microsoft Sql Data Sync
4. Conventional Script way via management studio.
But all the above tools showed that they have limited capacity. A user cannot work flawlessly on either of the tool.

1. In cerebrata's tool - the main drawback was its field for Application User Name and Application Key , which my admin havent shared. Also there is manual mapping of fields between azure and local.
2. Sql Azure Migration wizard - generates scripts and executed too but with lots of error . I was using its version 2.1. Also it very slow. It seems that its a replica of Sql Srvr Mgmt Studio.
3. Sql Data Sync :- I found it cool as its a MS product but it has limitation too that it only connects with Windows Authentication based local sql server, or you need to explicitly allow the required but. Even after allowing while syncing , I got some Sql Azure Provisioning Error.

4 Sql Srvr Mgmt Studio :- This is most easiest way but requires a lot of manual work to do before actual migration. What i did is that I generated a script of entire db (almost 101123 lines of code for single db) and tried to execute on azure. On the very first time i faced some keyword mismatch error . Finally i removed all line after primary key declaration that `With (Padding = Off ....)`or something similar and also `On Primary`  then i executed , but still got error on `Set Identity Insert On`. After doing a lot of hard work in removing unwanted lines waited more than 2 hrs to completed the script remotely, i got no Errors , errors and errors.

So you guys are requested to please suggest me any good alternative stated than above or i am lacking something and can do more with above.

Thanks

Amit Ranjan

Comment: Hi ,I know not a relevant comment but can anybody tell me what is bounty here "start a bounty". What's its usage? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem recently, running through the options you've listed.

You might give a try to [Red-Gate beta for Azure](http://www.red-gate.com/Azure) (free for a few months). I found their tools to be quite good for SQL schema and data replication.

Never tried the Azure build myself, though (I migrated tables manually by the time I was told about the offer).

Comment: there was a form and a broken link of sql azure download... i knew about red gate and their robust tools. lemme check once..