# Are there any issues and/or gotchas going from SQL Server Express 2008 to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm sure there are, I'm wondering what they are and if there is any upgrade/conversion documentation relative to taking a standard SQL server database and moving it to SQL Azure.

Comment: I'm not an Azure expert, but I found the following on SO that may help a bit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178929/sql-2008-developer-to-sql-azure-migration

It's not what you're looking for, but I wanted to provide you with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Jason's link, you should check out these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336250.aspx

See if there's any features you're using that's missing. If not, go go go :-)

Comment: As long as I've got a pretty vanilla database, I should be in good shape then, according to those links...?

Answer (score 2):

I would try running the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to check if there's anything that's not obvious that you might have missed.